# AngularJS: input cleaning doesn't work in state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel

I've got some problem. I wrote function which cleans input by button click, but it doesn't work when I use $stateProvider and cleaning is implemented in state.

app.js:

```
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']); 
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/first");

        $stateProvider
        .state("first", {
            url: "/first",
            templateUrl: "first.html"
        })
        .state("second", {
            url: "/second",
            templateUrl: "second.html"
        });

    });

    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

        $scope.searchAll = "";

        $scope.clearSearch = function () {
            $scope.searchAll = "";
        };
    });
</script>
```

page:

```
<body ng-controller = "ctrl">
<div class = "container" >

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a ng-href="#/first">First</a></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a ng-href="#/second">Second</a></button>
    <br>
    <ui-view><ui-view>
</div>
</body>
```

State first:

```
FIRST SIDE!!!!!
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchAll"></input> 
<a  href=""  data-ng-click="clearSearch()">X</a>
```

State second:

```
SECOND SIDE!!!!
```

Comment: why are you doing this ??? its so simple why are u using this in state ?

Comment: I need to change pages without refreshing and one of this pages contains input which has to be cleaned by button. Its simple, but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure from your description, but at a guess the attributes in your state templates will not be getting bound to the $scope of your controller as they are not present at the time when your full page controller is instantiated.

So, a few things:

You are better off having a separate controller for each of the ui-views rather than having a single controller for the full page, that way the controller is bound to the individual state template when you move to that state.

```
$stateProvider
    .state("first", {
        url: "/first",
        templateUrl: "first.html",
        controller: 'FirstCtrl as first'
    })
```

Rather than have an empty href for the clear button which can cause browser refreshes unless you add a e.preventDefault(); to the click event it is easier to use a span or div tag.

Use ui-srefs for the links to each state rather than ng-href, eg.

```
<a ui-sref="first">First</a>
```

Finally, it is a good time to stop using $scope as it is disappearing in Angular 2, and is no longer best practice in Angular 1.* apps - use controller as syntax instead - https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

See your code with above changes at https://plnkr.co/edit/3yStlPEozNGM886nEoXg?p=preview - and clear button works as expected

Comment: Ok. Thank you soo much, but two controllers give me another problem. How can I transfer variables between these two controllers? Should I use localStorage or something else?

Comment: The best way to do it would be to have a service, probably overkill for this small example, but that is what scales best - will add this to the plunkr, but won't have time until tomorrow sorry.

Comment: I added a basic service to the plunkr to show how this can be used to share data between controllers. You should try and keep controllers focused on a single view  and move reusable logic and data to services.